# linux kill command - how it works?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kill, kill-process

My question is a bit theoretical. 
Lets say I have a process with PID 10, in order to terminate it I can use both `exit` and `kill`. 
`exit` command bring the process to Zombie state and later the process is beeing removed thru the `release_task()` func.

But what happens when kill is called on a process ? Does kill call exit ? Do the process become zombie?

 I really dont understand how `kill`works behind the scenes and which kernel function do the job

If it changes anything - im working (actually studying) on a v2.4.18 machine

Thank you very much

Comment: try "man kill" and you will get a brief...

Comment: "man 2 kill" might be better.

Comment: This question basically asks "How does Linux process management work?", and it's not a simple answer. [This external page](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-5.html) goes through some of the basics of signals from a userland point of view.

Comment: Hi, Thank you - I read the man pages but I couldnt find an answer.. I know that my question is a bit hard to answer, but my main interest in to know - when a process is beeing "killed", does his data is beeing removed using the exit\release task procedures, or thru a different procedure.
Moreover, how can I know if a process was killed or was "exited"